# How to migrate my wordpress site to virtual site?

Tags: wordpress, virtualhost

I've a Wordpress site in mamp running on port localhost:80. I want to host it to the virtual host. In Google, I'm getting solutions with a new installation of WordPress project. But I want to know how to migrate an existing site to virtual host. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone wordpress site for the develope purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705127/how-to-clone-wordpress-site-for-the-develope-purpose)

Comment: @ArtCore7 My site is not hosted to the server. It's running on mamp local server. I want to create a virtual host using localhost.